# Positioning and Sizing Buttons in GTK#

Tags: c#, mono, gtk, gtk#, xamarin-studio

Im trying to create a UI in GTK#(GTK .NET).I have created a window,pulled in a vbox,and on the top vbox i placed a button.But the button occupies the entire space.How can i reduce the button size and fix its position.

I have seen there is a `fixed container`,should i pull it in and avoid using vbox?
The UI/window will be of fixed size anyway ie:user cannot change the size

Could some one explain

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To build a nice sizeable UI you **should** use containers like vbox or hbox. If you want a monolitic window you may use **Fixed** container and manually set positions of controls like in WinFroms  (although you may do it with vbox and hbox too). To control height and width you may set **WidthRequest** and **HeightRequest** properties. Also you may use **Aligement** control to set left/right and top/bottom paddings relatively to the current control's position. (sorry for russian labels on the screen):

[image]

Comment: Thanks.The UI will not be resizable.so i think i will go with Fixed.Also i cannot import glade files in monodevelop,some error pops up when i try to do it

Comment: @techno Current version of MD/Xamarin uses GTK# based on GTK+ 2. If I'm not mistaken latest Glade version uses GTK+ 3. May be this is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had this probleb too. Then I added container via Graphical Designer and put all necessary widgets throught code like this:

```
Label lab = new Label("Record");//widget you want to add
vbox1.PackStart(lab, false, false, 3);//method that add a widget into a Box containers
vbox1.ShowAll();
```

Alternativly you can create an object of ContainerChilc class and set all properties you need. Than just use `add()` method.